# How to create OrderItem using trigger

Tags: trigger

How to create same orderItem(some field are modified) when I create any OrderItem record related to order using trigger?

Comment: Hello Ravi, Welcome SFSE, What you have tried so far? can you paste the code here?

Comment: Yes, please, show as what it is that you have tried so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by a simple trigger on **OrderItem** Object on event  **afterInsert** of like below:-

Clone method will give you a duplicate OrderItem record : [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone)

```
trigger OrderItemTrigger on OrderItem (after insert) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce()){
        List<OrderItem> orderItemsToInsert = new List<OrderItem>();
        for(OrderItem record: Trigger.new){
            OrderItem newOrderItem = record.clone(false, true, false, false);
         //   newOrderItem.field =''; //make changes on fields you want

            orderItemsToInsert.add(newOrderItem  );
        }
        Database.insert(orderItemsToInsert );

    }   
}
```

Also, add the recursive check code in your Org, because you do not want to keep on adding new order Items recursively.

```
public Class checkRecursive{

    private static boolean run = true;

    public static boolean runOnce(){

    if(run){
     run=false;
     return true;  
    }
    else{
        return run;
    }

    }
}
```